# how ios UI update code defined for use with main dispatch

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, user-interface, grand-central-dispatch

I've been reading a lot of example code, i know that generally you want the **code that updates your UI** to execute on the main thread. And xcode will complain, at runtime, if i m missing something. Only sometimes though.

So how is **code that updates your UI** actually defined?
Is presenting an alert updating the UI? calling reloadData() on a UITableView? What about simply setting the text of a UILabel?
Especially with these three, i've been seeing and using it both ways in my app and can't really figure out a rule. Especially since xcode lets me get away with both... sometimes.

Edit: Ohh, i understand where my confusion came from. I thought it was random what thread you were on. But you are actually "always" on the main thread, unless you do something like a task, which runs on a background thread.

So the Main Thread Checker didn't actually let me "get away" with using reload() and changing labels in my viewController falsely. It's just that i was guaranteed to be on the main thread.

I thought i had to suddenly wrap every single label change everywhere in dispatch.async.

Comment: If something on the screen changes, it's updating the UI. Just about anything done with a class starting with `UI` needs to be on the main queue. There are few exceptions.

Comment: User Interface, or UI, is basically any and everything that you see on screen/viewport. It can be a label. It can be a table view. It can be a button. Now if any of the values related to them are changing. For example. text of label, content of table view, color of button, its called updating the UI and Apple recommends it to be done on main thread. If not then it will make your app looked freezed up, delaying the changes that were intended to be immediate. This amounts to BAD User Experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xcode *letting* you do something does not mean you *should* do that thing.**

Reloading a table view, showing an alert, and changing a label's text are all UI updates. They all change what you see on screen, so they are UI updates. Always do these on the main thread.

Things that are not UI changes: sending HTTP requests, crunching numbers, loading data from some database. They don't change what you see on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You must update your UI on main thread so that user can not feel some lag or disturbance during interacting with your UI. i.e. reload table, change text, change color, etc.

And you can perform your time taking operations on background thread so that your app performs well during the operations. i.e. HTTP requests, Database operations, long running loops, large nested conditions etc.

You can write your code like this....

```
// define these methods in your helper class or wherever you want.
public func BACKGROUND_QUEUE(_ codeBlock:@escaping (() -> Void)) -> Void {
    return DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async(execute: codeBlock)
}

public func MAIN_QUEUE(_ codeBlock:@escaping (() -> Void)) -> Void {
    return DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: codeBlock)
}
```

and use like this.

```
func fetchData() {

    BACKGROUND_QUEUE {
        //your http request to get some text
        let text = yourResult
        MAIN_QUEUE {
            textLabel.text = text
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule “update the UI only on the main thread” covers only part of the truth, better stick to what the [UIKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit) states:

> **Important**
>   Use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread or main
>   dispatch queue, unless otherwise indicated. This restriction
>   particularly applies to classes derived from UIResponder or that
>   involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

This restriction applies not only to (visible) updates of what is presented to the user, but to *any* UIKit classes, unless otherwise specified.

As an example, accessing the applications delegate does not affect the
UI, but doing so on a non-main thread causes a “Main Thread Checker violation”:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let shared = UIApplication.shared.delegate
}

// Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication delegate]
```